# How to get all the Students enrolled to a list of Specific Courses say (1 and 2) in a many to many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, django-queryset

I'm trying to get all the Students which are enrolled to a list of specific courses (Say Course 1 and Course 2).

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Student name")
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course, related_name="students", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Course Name")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

If I do:

```
result = Student.objects.filter(courses__in=[1,2])
```

I get all the Students who are enrolled with either course 1 or course 2.
I'm interested only in students who are enrolled in both courses.

The below code works but I think it's not the best way to accomplish this:

```
all_students = Student.objects.all()
stud_id = []
for student in all_students:
    course_list = list(student.courses.values_list('pk', flat=True))
    check = all(item in course_list for item in [1,2])
    if check:
        stud_id.append(student.id)
studs = Student.objects.filter(id__in=stud_id)
```

The idea is to not loop over every student to find if they're enrolled to the given set of courses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ashley H. indicated, but instead:

```
result = Student.objects.filter(courses__id=1).filter(courses__id=2)
```

So if we have:

```
Joe Ben: Math, Computing, Machine Learning
Ray Youth: Math, Computing
Elli Vader: Computing
```

The result would be: Joe Ben, Ray Youth. I assume this is what is needed. Can you correct me if not?

Comment: @akshayjain please dont forget to select my answer as the solution if it helped

Comment: In addition, stacking multiple ORM filters translates into a single query with a stack of Inner Joins, one per course. So, still good.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, sorry @mseromenho missed selecting your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.

(1) Your `related_name` for courses on your student model is a little confusing. The idea of the related name is to be able to do a 'backwards' lookup on the model the relationship is defined on from the model the replationship is not defined on. Here, you'd want to be able to start with your `Course` model and use that `related_name` to get a list of students in the course(s). So instead of `related_name="course_name"`, I would recommend `related_name="students"`.

(2) The `__in` suffix indeed matches to anything in the list. If you want both, you have to explicitly filter for both. So, your query would be:

```
result = Student.objects.filter(courses__id=1).filter(courses__id=2)
```

This should only return students who are in BOTH courses.

Comment: I agree with the confusion in the related_name. But, when I try to do follow step 2, I get the error:
`SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated: courses__id`

Comment: Yep, sorry about that - @mseromenho has the solution and I will update my answer.

Comment: Agree, mseromenho has the solution and hopefully the OP @AkshayJain will credit him with the answer.